# Ninject 2.0: Passing different parameters depending on implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2, constructor-injection

I have just started to work with Ninject 2.0 with ASP.NET MVC 2.
So, I have an interface IMongoRepository and class MongoRepository.

MongoRepository receives a parameter string collection.

Depending on the collection I want to use, I pass in a different value in parameter for MongoRepository.
I hope I am phrasing this correctly, but how would I map different parameters depending on the Controller I am using?

For example, in the Article controller I would call:

```
_articlesRepository = new MongoRepository("Articles");
```

and in the PageController I would call:

```
_pagesController = new MongoRepository("Pages");
```

What I would like to do is just do constructor injection and just pass in IMongoRepository.
Any ideas or suggestions?

By the way, I am just learning about the IOC/DI; so, I am open to any tips from the IOC ninjas!
Thanks!

Comment: This link seems promising! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313940/ninject-to-bind-on-different-controllers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Bind<IMongoRepository>().To<MongoRepository>().WhenInjectedInto<ArticleController>().WithConstructorArgument("topic", "Article");
Bind<IMongoRepository>().To<MongoRepository>().WhenInjectedInto<PagesController>().WithConstructorArgument("topic", "Pages");
```

Assuming that the constructor's argument is called `topic`.